# LEFT JOIN taking ages in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a mySQL query with a LEFT JOIN that is taking over 30 seconds to run and I need to drastically speed it up. The query is as follows:

```
SELECT asset.asset_id, schedule.schedule_name, asset.asset_type, asset_sign.sign_type, 
       asset.creation_date, asset.update_date, asset.sms, asset.gps, survey.location, 
       survey.address, asset.condition_grade, 
       asset.performance_grade, asset.aesthetics_grade  
FROM survey, SCHEDULE, asset 
  LEFT JOIN asset_sign 
   ON asset_sign.asset_id = asset.asset_id 
WHERE asset.sms = survey.sms 
      AND asset.deletion_date='0000-00-00' 
      AND asset.schedule_id = schedule.schedule_id 
      AND schedule.schedule_id = '1'
```

The Asset and Asset Tables are pretty large with around 10,000 lines.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

1. make sure that asset_sign.asset_id is indexed
2. make sure that asset.asset_id is indexed
3. Rewrite your query for clarity:

   ```
   SELECT <whatever> 
   FROM survey  
       JOIN asset ON asset.sms = survey.sms  
       JOIN schedule ON asset.schedule_id = schedule.schedule_id  
       LEFT JOIN asset_sign ON asset_sign.asset_id = asset.asset_id  
   WHERE asset.deletion_date='0000-00-00'  
       AND schedule.schedule_id = '1'
   ```
4. make sure that asset.sms is indexed
5. make sure that survey.sms is indexed
6. make sure that asset.schedule_id is indexed
7. make sure that schedule.schedule_id is indexed

This is at a minimum as you should be joining on things that are indexed. You can also:

8. index the columns you are using in your WHERE clause
9. move the conditionals in your WHERE clause into their respective JOIN conditions so that the filtering happens at the JOIN step instead of after everything has been joined.

   ```
   SELECT <whatever> 
   FROM survey  
       JOIN asset ON asset.sms = survey.sms AND asset.deletion_date='0000-00-00'
       JOIN schedule ON asset.schedule_id = schedule.schedule_id AND schedule.schedule_id = '1'
       LEFT JOIN asset_sign ON asset_sign.asset_id = asset.asset_id
   ```

Comment: Thanks heaps. I have added the indexes and reformatted the query and it is better for sure but still not quite where I would like it to be, I think I may have to just add the sign_type field to the main asset table and maintain it there too and avoid using a left join. Cheers.

Comment: @ScottThompson I doubt that it's the left join that's really hurting you. 10k records is not a lot. Try moving your 2 where statements to the 2 ON clauses that they are related to. I'm updating the comment to show you.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider modifying your query to have the proper joins like below. Also, move the conditions from `WHERE` to `JOIN ON` clause to have a proper outer join effect.

```
SELECT asset.asset_id, 
       schedule.schedule_name, 
       asset.asset_type, 
       asset_sign.sign_type, 
       asset.creation_date, 
       asset.update_date, 
       asset.sms, 
       asset.gps, 
       survey.location, 
       survey.address, asset.condition_grade, 
       asset.performance_grade, asset.aesthetics_grade  
FROM survey 
LEFT JOIN assest ON asset.sms = survey.sms 
AND asset.deletion_date='0000-00-00'
LEFT JOIN asset_sign ON asset_sign.asset_id = asset.asset_id 
LEFT JOIN SCHEDULE ON asset.schedule_id = schedule.schedule_id  
AND schedule.schedule_id = '1';
```

Comment: Thanks mate but that seems to take twice as long to run and also returns a heap of null lines. Even if I change the first left join to a normal join then it still takes too long. Thanks for trying though.